# Maven updating .project files, project can no longer successfully build

Tags: java, eclipse, maven

I am using Maven in Eclipse Kepler with JRE 1.7.09 for a large project at work. We have a few hundred plugins for our Maven project. Initially, after checking everything out from our Git/SVN repos, I am able to do a Maven Clean/Install without a single issue. But after some time, all of my projects update and I can no longer perform a successful build. I also get errors by almost every project (which is discouraging considering there are about 200 in my workspace).

Comparing my local copy and the HEAD version, the only differences are the .project files. In my workspace version, most of the information has been completely removed. Updating these files to the HEAD restores the content and resolves the errors...but updating 200+ .project files everytime it breaks isn't the most efficient.

If it helps, I am also a victim of the infinite SVN Status Cache Update error.

Any tips would be appreciated. I would really love to fix this shit so I can get back to actual work.

Thanks!

Edit:
The first error was nonsense, so I removed the Maven nature from the offending package. Now I am getting this --

```
[ERROR] QueryResult cannot be resolved to a type
[ERROR] <dir/file.java>:[152,0]
[ERROR] List<Status> tweets = result.getTweets();
[ERROR] ^^^^^^
[ERROR] Status cannot be resolved to a type
[ERROR] <dir/file.java>:[166,0]
[ERROR] private Table covertResultIntoTable(List<Status> statuses) {
[ERROR] ^^^^^^
[ERROR] Status cannot be resolved to a type
[ERROR] <dir/file.java>:[172,0]
[ERROR] for (Status status : statuses) {
[ERROR] ^^^^^^
[ERROR] Status cannot be resolved to a type
[ERROR] 30 problems (30 errors)
```

I can export this package without a single error and all of the types come from a .JAR that has been added to the build path.

Comment: What errors you actually got ?

Comment: Edited the original post with the errors. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Run on the console:
    mvn clean eclipse:eclipse 
or load it on eclipse after installing the m2 plugin

Please note I specified OR, do not do both :)